# Debugging using makefile flags in C

Tags: c, debugging, makefile, compiler-flags

I need to set up a way to debug my program from the make file. Specifically, when I type `make -B FLAG=-DNDEBUG` I need the program to run normally. But when this flag is not present I need a few `assert()` commands throughout the code to run.

To clarify I need to know how to check if this flag is not present from within my C code, I'd assume it has something to do with `#ifndef`, I just don't know where to go from there.

Forgive my ignorance, any response would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the `assert` macro from the standard library (`#define`d in `<assert.h>`) then you don't have to do anything. The library already takes care of the `NDEBUG` flag.

If you want to make your own code do things only if the macro is / is not `#define`d, use an `#ifdef` as you already suspect in your question.

For example, we might have a condition that is too complex to put into a single `assert` expression so we want a variable for it.  But if the `assert` expands to nothing, then we don't want that value computed.  So we might use something like this.

```
int
questionable(const int * numbers, size_t length)
{
#ifndef NDEBUG
  /* Assert that the numbers are not all the same. */
  int min = INT_MAX;
  int max = INT_MIN;
  size_t i;
  for (i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
      if (numbers[i] < min)
        min = numbers[i];
      if (numbers[i] > max)
        max = numbers[i];
    }
  assert(length >= 2);
  assert(max > min);
#endif
  /* Now do what you're supposed to do with the numbers... */
  return 0;
}
```

Be warned that this coding style makes for hard to read code and is *asking* for [Heisenbugs](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/H/heisenbug.html) that are extremely difficult to debug. A much better way to express this is to use functions.

```
/* 1st helper function */
static int
minimum(const int * numbers, size_t length)
{
  int min = INT_MAX;
  size_t i;
  for (i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
      if (numbers[i] < min)
        min = numbers[i];
    }
  return min;
}

/* 2nd helper function */
static int
maximum(const int * numbers, size_t length)
{
  int max = INT_MIN;
  size_t i;
  for (i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
      if (numbers[i] > max)
        max = numbers[i];
    }
  return max;
}

/* your actual function */
int
better(const int * numbers, int length)
{
  /* no nasty `#ifdef`s */
  assert(length >= 2);
  assert(minimum(numbers, length) < maximum(numbers, length));
  /* Now do what you're supposed to do with the numbers... */
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When calling make with or without "FLAG=-DNDEBUG" you will need rules like this in your Makefile:

`%.o: %.c
        gcc -c $(FLAG) $<`

In your C code you will need something like this:

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
  fprintf(stderr, "My trace message\n");
#endif
```